# Sencha ExtJS 7 modern FileInput extend by Drag & Drop

Tags: file-upload, extjs

I'm trien to add Drag&Drop feature to sencha extjs 7.6 modern fileinput. I couldnt find a config or plugin. So I made a modified version to fix multiple bug and want to add drag and drop to it. I can get files from drop, but how do I add them to sencha fileinput field?

I tried extending fileinput field like this:

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3pj0

```
Ext.define('crm.view.fields.FileFieldMulti', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.File',
    xtype: 'filefieldmulti',

      applyName: function(name) {
       // var multiple;
        var multiple = this.config.multiple;
        if (name) {
            if (multiple && name.substr(-2, 2) !== "[]") {
                name += "[]";
            }
            else if ((!multiple) && name.substr(-2, 2) === "[]") {
                name = name.substr(0, name.length - 2);
            }
        }

        return name;
    },

    listeners: {

        drop: {
            element: 'element',
            fn: function(e) {
                DnD_drop(e);
            },
        },

        dragstart: {
            element: 'element',
            fn: function(e) {
                DnD_addDropZone(e);
            },
        },

        dragenter: {
            element: 'element',
            fn: function(e) {
                DnD_addDropZone(e);
            },
        },

        dragover: {
            element: 'element',
            fn: function(e) {
                DnD_addDropZone(e);
            },
        },

        dragleave: {
            element: 'element',
            fn: function(e) { 
                DnD_removeDropZone(e);
            },
        },

        dragexit: {
            element: 'element',
            fn: function(e) {
                DnD_removeDropZone(e);
            },
        },

    },
    
});

function DnD_addDropZone(e) {
    if (!e.browserEvent.dataTransfer || Ext.Array.from(e.browserEvent.dataTransfer.types).indexOf('Files') === -1) {
        return;
    }

    e.stopEvent();

    // Ext.getCmp(e.currentTarget.id).addCls('drag-over');
}

function DnD_removeDropZone(e) {
    // var el = e.getTarget(),
        // thisEl = this.getEl();

    e.stopEvent();


    // if (el === thisEl.dom) {
        // Ext.getCmp(e.currentTarget.id).removeCls('drag-over');
        // return;
    // }

    // while (el !== thisEl.dom && el && el.parentNode) {
        // el = el.parentNode;
    // }

    // if (el !== thisEl.dom) {
        // Ext.getCmp(e.currentTarget.id).removeCls('drag-over');
    // }

}

function DnD_drop(e) {
    e.stopEvent();
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
    var elementTarget = Ext.getCmp(e.currentTarget.id);
    console.log(elementTarget);
    console.log(elementTarget.xtype);
    console.log(e.browserEvent.dataTransfer.files);
    console.log(elementTarget.getFileButton());
    // elementTarget.getFileButton().el.dom.files = e.browserEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    
    let tmpContainer = new DataTransfer();
      
    let value = [];

    if(e.browserEvent.dataTransfer.files.length > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0, len = e.browserEvent.dataTransfer.files.length; i < len; i++) {
            let fileInc = e.browserEvent.dataTransfer.files[i];
            // file = e.browserEvent.dataTransfer.files[i];
            // console.log(file.data);
            // console.log(file.getData());
            value.push(fileInc.name);
            let file = new File([fileInc], fileInc.name, {type:fileInc.name, lastModified:fileInc.lastModifiedDate});    

            // let file = new File(e.browserEvent.dataTransfer.files[i]);    
            tmpContainer.items.add(file);
        }
        value = value.join(', ');
        
    }
    console.log(tmpContainer.files);
    console.log(elementTarget.getFileButton());
    elementTarget.getFileButton().el.dom.files = tmpContainer.files;
    elementTarget.getFileButton().setValue(value);
    elementTarget.getFileButton().onChange();
    
    console.log(actionSheet.down('filefieldmulti').getFiles());
    
    // elementTarget.removeCls('drag-over');
}
```

But I cant get sencha filefield to accept files, how to add new files for example from blob to sencha fielfield?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a working solution, here it is: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3pk5